# Pagerank in website directories

Tags: seo, pagerank

I have a website that I want to work as a public-facing employee profile for people in my company. Each employee has a page like `http://companyname.com/[EmployeeName]`, and then users on the site have simple links between each other's profiles: for instance, all the people who work together have "works with" links between their profiles. The idea is for the profiles to be simple, lightweight pages, with editable content by the user, so that the companies/customers we work with can know the people here better. So - something like linkedin, but branded with our own company logo + design.

I want to know how these pages will respond to google pagerank. Will internal links between employees increase the pagerank of the user's profile? Will the pagerank still work given that I am doing some url-rewriting to make the profiles have the `companyname.com/[employeename]` format? If someone searches on google for an employee's name, will the profiles appear correctly in the search results?

When developing the site, I assumed 'yes' to all these things, but now we are getting ready to launch I need confirmation that these assumptions were correct. Also, are there any other complications that I should know about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to know how these pages will respond to google pagerank. Will
>   internal links between employees increase the pagerank of the user's
>   profile?

PageRank is per page, so any page that is accessible to Google will have PageRank. PageRank can be increased by accumulating links from other pages. These include pages from the same website.

> Will the pagerank still work given that I am doing some url-rewriting
>   to make the profiles have the companyname.com/[employeename] format?

User agents (i.e. browsers and search engines) don't know what URL rewriting is. They only see the URL they are provided and the content that is provided when that URL is requested. So your pages will still have PR when using mod_rewrite.

> If someone searches on google for an employee's name, will the
>   profiles appear correctly in the search results?

Yes.